Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Uncaught exception in event handler with indexedDB
I am using vue 3 with indexedDB through this library: 'https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb'
In my component:
const [dataA, dataB] = await Promise.all([
   getDataA(),
   getDataB(),
])

In my typescript file:
let dbInstance: any
const openDB = async () => {
  try {
    if (!dbInstance) {
      dbInstance = await openDB('test')
    }
    return dbInstance
  } catch (e: any) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
const getDataA = async () => {
  const db = await openDB()
  const store = db.transaction('A').objectStore('A')
  const result = await store.getAll()
  return result
}
const getDataB = async () => {
  const db = await openDB()
  const store = db.transaction('B').objectStore('B')
  const result = await store.getAll()
  return result
}

I got an error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Uncaught exception in event handler.
Have anyone ever met this case? And What am I doing wrong?

One of the promises in the array for Promise.all() rejected and therefore you you have to handle rejection reason.
try {
   const [dataA, dataB] = await Promise.all([
     getDataA(),
     getDataB(),
   ])
} catch (error) {
  if (!(error instanceof Error)) {
    throw error
  }

  throw new Error("Failed to get data A and B", { cause: error })
}

This part is a big sus, since you don't handle the error:
try {
  if (!dbInstance) {
    dbInstance = await openDB('test')
  }
  return dbInstance
} catch (e: any) {
  console.error(e)
}

Don't do this within random async procedures without known call context, just let the error propagate to the call site so you could presumably show the error message within the GUI. The only thing these kind of procedures can do with errors is to try to recover or re-throw in some way if they can't.

thanks for your answer. I wrapped everything inside try catch blocks and temporarily use console.error to know what is exactly happening, but everything I got is 'Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Uncaught exception in event handler.'

"Wrapping everything in try...catch blocks" is not going to aid in debugging if you don't rethrow/handle errors, especially if you swallow errors like in openDB() function. Just call it without a try...catch and the underlying error will be shown.
